# get sublime text 3 to close certain windows on quit

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

Is there any way to write a script that will tell sublime to close specific windows on quit?

I've tried setting a window's remember_open_files setting to false, and I've tried using python's atexit library to run the close window command. So far no luck

Comment: Why not use an [`EventListener`](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime_plugin.EventListener)?

Comment: none exists for pre-quitting events

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "specific windows" - sublime windows? sublime views? Other application windows?

You can detect window close with `EventListener`. There is no direct pre-quitting event, but you can use view's `on_close` function and check if there is any widnows in `sublime.windows()`.

`def on_close(self, view):
    if not sublime.windows():
        self.close_specific_windows()`

Be aware that this function will be called for each opened view (file) in sublime.